# Custom TFS build definition templates across projects

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS provides a list of templates that I can use for new build definitions:
[image: Build Tab]

Once I've used "Save as template..." on a build definition, I can then use it as a template *within* that project:

[image: Custom Tab]

But when I switch to a *different* project, that custom template is no longer available.

How can I create a build template that I can use in *any* project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to directly copy or sync a vNext build definition template between team projects on the Web Portal. The build definition template is only for the present team project. So you need to create a build definition template for each team project.

And also there have been a feature request in **user voice**, you can vote up and monitor it

> **VSO build vnext: share build templates between projects**
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8468566-vso-build-vnext-share-build-templates-between-pro

---

However, for **a workaround**, you can use the REST API to perform this. Here is an example shown in the [blog](http://www.ericksegaar.com/2015/10/16/using-json-via-rest-to-create-build-definitions-in-vso/).

It shows how to **get the JSON response of a build definition** and again using the same reference to make a new one in the project you desire.

You can also take a look at this nice article: [How to move build definitions in TFS to other projects using the REST API](https://writeabout.net/2016/03/03/how-to-move-build-definitions-in-tfs-to-other-projects-using-the-rest-api/)

Comment: Then how does the list under the Build tab get populated? Can things be added there directly?

Comment: I found this [this explanation](https://writeabout.net/2016/03/03/how-to-move-build-definitions-in-tfs-to-other-projects-using-the-rest-api/) of how to use the REST API to do this helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a nice article!

Answer (score 0):

As for now it is not supported but you can vote it up to make it happen faster:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8468566-vso-build-vnext-share-build-templates-between-pro